# Compiling v8js extension after V8 was built with gn build (as opposed to gyp)

Tags: php, v8

Google has decided to deprecate gyp builds of V8. The recommended method is to build with gn.

However, PHP extension v8js fails to find required libraries and exits with:

```
checking for V8 Javascript Engine... yes, shared
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for C standard version... c++11
checking how to allow c++11 narrowing... -Wno-narrowing
checking for V8 version... NONE
configure: error: could not determine libv8 version
```

What needs to be done to compile PHP v8js extension after V8 is compiled with gn?

Thanks!

Comment: gyp is still fully supported on platforms where gn doesn't work yet.   Use gyp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of experimentation I've successfully compiled v8js against V8 that was built with gn (as opposed to now-deprecated gyp).

Follow initial checkout instructions https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20GN.

After `tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release` step do this:

```
$ nano out.gn/x64.release/args.gn
```

It should looks like this:

```
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
is_component_build = true
v8_enable_i18n_support = false
```

At this point I could not figure out how to correctly build i18n support.

Not sure if this is really required, but I also updated `out.gn/x64.release/v8_build_config.json` with: **"v8_enable_i18n_support": false**.

Compile (takes about 45 minutes):

```
$ ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
```

Once compiled:

```
$ cp out.gn/x64.release/lib*.so /usr/lib/ && cp -R include/* /usr/include
$ cp out.gn/x64.release/natives_blob.bin /usr/lib
$ cp out.gn/x64.release/snapshot_blob.bin /usr/lib
$ cd out.gn/x64.release/obj
$ ar rcsDT libv8_libplatform.a v8_libplatform/*.o
$ echo -e "create /usr/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib /usr/local/src/v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M
```

After that check out v8js and compile as usual:

```
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

Comment: I do extracly what you said, but still missing libv8_libplatform.a, `[root@osboxes obj]# echo -e "create /usr/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib /usr/local/src/v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M
ar: /usr/local/src/v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've been working for 4 days of this issue and no luck

Answer (score 0):

echo -e "create/usr/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib /usr/local/src/v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M

print : **/usr/local/src/v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/libv8_libplatform.a: No such file or directory**

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your answer and use "Code Sample" for greater readability.